# could not find adb:do you have android sdk installed and the tools + platform-tools folders added to your PATH?

Tags: android, path, adb, emulation, appium

Actually I have set the path in Environment variables.

By adding new path like ANDROID_HOME and value set to `D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk`
and in systems variables I have edited the path as `PATH` and the value set to `D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\tools\;D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platform-tools\`
When I run the web driver script using junit I am getting the following error

**`A new session could not be created. (Original error:could not find adb:do you have android sdk installed and the tools + platform - tools folders added to your PATH?)`**

I have created script in web-driver using JUnit and I have launched emulator. And I have started appium server. I am not getting any error in my coding.

Please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have adb under platform-tools or tools? check if that is true.

For ex: in mac os if you dl the standalone sdk you do not get a proper build and you have to update your platform tools/tools.

You can open your sdk manager and choose to update your platform tools/tools/build tools if you happen to have an empty/incomplete version of either.

Hope that resolves your issue.